# What is the fastest way to make identically formatted plots with different datasets in the same sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have multiple datasets in one Excel sheet. Each column in a given dataset is the same length of the corresponding column in every other dataset, and corresponds to the same parameter. I need to make a separate identically formatted plot for each dataset.

For example, lets say I have 30 datasets, each comprised of 50 columns - one x vector and 49 y vectors. Each dataset begins 250 rows below the beginning of previous dataset.

What is the most efficient, or 'proper' way to generate 30 identically formatted plots, each corresponding to a different dataset?

Comment: What have you tried? What do your datasets look like? Can you mock them up for us? I are you looking for a method that works, or specifically for the method that runs most quickly? Do you already have something that works? Why are you concerned it may not be fast enough?

Comment: Did U mean a GRAPH (formatted plots),, plz [edit] your post & be specific and loud all about your need, will help us to fix the issue,, also share some screen shots. Or are you taking about identical TABELs ?